# Wordpress and tag pages title

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to know how to remove the word "archives" from a category or tag page title of a WordPress theme? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the official docs of [get_the_archive_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/). You can modify the content through filter like below.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {
        if( is_category() ) {
            $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
        }
        return $title;
    });
```